# What are my options for navigating through subroutines?

Tags: python

Suppose I want a program `Foo.py` which has some arbitrary routines `Bar()`, `Quux()`, and `Fizz()`. Let's say that the *usual* order of execution from a procedural perspective should be `Bar() -> Quux() -> Fizz()`. However, `Fizz()` should conditionally call a function `Buzz()` depending on some runtime action, and calling `Buzz()` at any time during `Fizz()` should return the process back to `Quux()`.

I have a fair understanding of how concurrent processes can be implemented in assembly using system calls depending on the architecture, but what options are available to me in Python, where I can't – and frankly would prefer not to – use lots of jumps and directly move an instruction pointer around? When searching for an answer, I found loops and recursion as a suggestion for going back in a program. I don't think a loop would work without stopping the `Fizz()` process to wait for the condition check for `Buzz()`, and I'm not sure how recursion could be implemented in this scenario either. (My `Buzz()` would be like a "Back" button on a GUI).

Comment: Take a look at [coroutines](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/coroutines.html) in python.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, was about to say the same

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using coroutines (multithreading) will provide the desired concurrent functionality. Source in the comments of the question and of user2357112's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything fancy here. The usual structured programming tools will work fine. Have `Fizz` return after calling `Buzz`, and have it return an indicator saying whether to go back to `Quux`:

```
Bar()
while True:
    Quux()
    if not Fizz():
        break
```

(If `Buzz`'s only effect is supposed to be returning execution to `Quux`, don't have a `Buzz` at all and just return.)

Comment: simple, i like it. but maybe it will not work properly on depending wich computation should be dont on the functions.

Comment: This is neat, but wouldn't this still require an explicit condition check, and thus a process stop, during `Fizz` to return to `Quux`?

Comment: @ImInfinite313: You're going to have to explain what you mean by "process stop". You *want* Fizz to stop, don't you? If you're thinking of something like branch misprediction and pipeline flushing, or if you want multithreaded concurrent execution, you'll need to make that clearer.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Seems multithreading is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @ImInfinite313: I suspect you're still confused somewhere - for example, the "lots of jumps and directly move an instruction pointer around" solution you talked about in assembly wouldn't actually be concurrent in any way. There's a lot in this situation to suggest that you may be worrying about the wrong things or not actually solving the problems you think you're solving, but we can't really tell.

Comment: If I moved the instruction pointer on some call stack and used system interrupts to switch around between processes, wouldn't that be able to handle "concurrent" processes? That's what multithreading looks like it's doing too.

Comment: @ImInfinite313: The "system interrupts to switch around between processes" part might be concurrent, but modern systems don't actually require you to perform explicit thread or process switches, and in the systems that did require that, everything else would still be stuck waiting while `Buzz` runs. It'd be concurrent but not parallel. (Incidentally, Python multithreading is also concurrent but not parallel, due to the Global Interpreter Lock.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps flow like the below.  `Fizz` loops until some condition evokes a call to `Buzz`.  The same check that triggers the call breaks the loop.

```
import random

def Buzz():
    print ("Buzz")

def Fizz():
    print ("Fizz")
    while True:
        flip = random.random()
        print ("  ", flip)
        if flip <= 0.5:
            Buzz()
            break

def Quux():
    print ("Quux")
    Fizz()
    print ("Back in Quux")

def Bar():
    print ("Bar")
    Quux()

Bar()
```

Output:

```
Bar
Quux
Fizz
   0.88313135192614
   0.9782005471906149
   0.6899740417799126
   0.724911154764598
   0.6193573809551899
   0.3713918176393549
Buzz
Back in Quux
```